# Create a function with dynamic ID

Tags: javascript, html

hey i am trying to create a function with a dynamic ID to create a button and when i click it create a function.

```js
var OperatorID = 0;

function AddFilterW() {
  var x = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  x.innerHTML = 'AND';
  x.setAttribute("id", `OperatorID_${OperatorID}`);
  x.setAttribute("onclick", `changeOperator(OperatorID_${OperatorID})`);
}

OperatorID++;

function changeOperator(Clicked_ID) {
  if (document.getElementById(`OperatorID_${OperatorID}`).innerHTML == 'AND') {
    document.getElementById(`OperatorID_${OperatorID}`).innerHTML = 'OR';
  } else if (document.getElementById(`OperatorID_${OperatorID}`).innerHTML == 'OR') {
    document.getElementById(`OperatorID_${OperatorID}`).innerHTML = 'AND';
  }
};
```

Comment: This seems like a roundabout way of going at it. You can just attach a click handler which when executed will have `this` set to the element. So you don't need the gymnastics with setting the `onclick` attribute to call a specific function with a specific ID, you just need one and then you do `this.innerHTML` instead of  the whole lookup `document.getElementById(\`OperatorID_${OperatorID}\`).innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you call the function with the arg wrapped in an anonymous one.

```
function AddFilterW() {
 var x = document.createElement("BUTTON");
 x.innerHTML = 'AND';
 x.setAttribute("id", `OperatorID_${OperatorID}`);
 x.setAttribute("onclick", () => changeOperator(`OperatorID_${OperatorID}`));
}
```

Comment: It's even better to attach a click handler with `addEventListener` instead of setting the `onlclick` attribute.

Comment: I tried it the error is gone but i can't call the changeOperator function.